# Selecting Integers From A Dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset and want to select only the integer values from the `Time (h)` column, what would be the code using dplyr to achieve this? [Image of a section of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSX7I.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
max(data$`Time (h)`) # get the max value in the column
integers <- seq(1, 100, by=1) #replace the 100 value with the max
# then you'll have a list of all integers from 1 to whatever your max is

# find the integers in your data
integers_in_data <-
data %>%
filter(`Time (h)` %in% integers)
```